# C# LINQ NULL check

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, null, var

On my form I  want to disable the bt_rent button if the movie has no date in the bringback colum(date type) so it means the dvd is still out and not available for renting:

```
var j = (from s in db.Rentals where s.Movietitle == (string)listbox1.SelectedValue select s).FirstOrDefault();



if (j.Bringback==null)
{
    elerhetotext.Text = "The dvd is not available for renting";
    bt_rent.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    elerhetotext.Text = "Rentable";
    bt_rent.Enabled = true;
}
```

The error I get:

> *Nullreferenceexpection was unhandled by user code  (error at:if (j.Bringback==null)) Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.*

Comment: so j is NULL. what's the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing validation on **j** itself. It seems in this case there is no DVD with the name you're looking for so ideally you should validate if **j** is NULL as well, instead of

```
if (j.Bringback==null)
```

Do the following

```
if (j != null || (j != null && j.Bringback==null))
```

So you are checking if the DVD exists, and if it does, the 2nd part of the validation is based on j itself, and if Bringback is null.

Comment: `(j != null || (j != null && j.Bringback==null))` seems to be redundant and will effectively be the same as `(j != null)`, thus not checking `j.Bringback` at all.

Answer (score 1):

The Variavle j is a type of object Rental in the given code

```
<pre>
var j = (from s in db.Rentals where s.Movietitle == (string)listbox1.SelectedValue select s).FirstOrDefault();
</pre>
```

Chek j is null or not like

```
<pre>
if (j==null)
{
    elerhetotext.Text = "The dvd is not available for renting";
    bt_rent.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    elerhetotext.Text = "Rentable";
    bt_rent.Enabled = true;
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that `j` itself is `null`, so you would need to check that `j` is not `null` before accessing `j`'s members:

```
if (j == null) {
    elerhetotext.Text = "DVD/movie does not exist";
    bt_rent.Enabled = false;
} else if (j.Bringback == null) {
    elerhetotext.Text = "The dvd is not available for renting";
    bt_rent.Enabled = false;
} else {
    elerhetotext.Text = "Rentable";
    bt_rent.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is only an addition to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23193515/3902603) written by [mez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480139/mez)**

---

Using C# 6.0's [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) one could rewrite the code as:

```
var j = (from s in db.Rentals
         where s.Movietitle == (string)listbox1.SelectedValue
         select s).FirstOrDefault();

// checks whether `j´ is null or `j.Bringback´ is null
if (j?.Bringback == null)
{
    elerhetotext.Text = "The dvd is not available for renting";
    bt_rent.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    elerhetotext.Text = "Rentable";
    bt_rent.Enabled = true;
}
```

---

The statement

```
if (j != null || (j != null && j.Bringback==null))
```

would be rewritten as

```
if (j?.Bringback == null)
```