# azure method blows up if the records does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using this method from the azure mobile services tutorial:
`await todoTable.LookupAsync(id)`.  I have 2 rows in a table of id 1,2. 
If i do `await todoTable.LookupAsync(1)`, it works and return the record. If i do
 `await todoTable.LookupAsync(8)` to see how it's going to handle null, it just blows up with Not Found exception.

Thanks for help on this.

Comment: generally it's a good idea to test for null first with an if statement != Null

Comment: Hi, I have var q = await todoTable.LookupAsync(8). I know that record of id 8 does not exist in the database. So, with entity framework and Linq i do if q == null do stuff. i have no way to know if it's null. Basically, I want to query the table to see if a user id exist else give the user a message that they must register.

Comment: if you can't check for null, can you wrap it in a try catch and handle the possibility of returning error in your catch by prompting to create the id?

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but there could be some other exception with same name related to something else.

Comment: check this question out, hopefully the answer will provide some insight on checking for null (I have not ventured into linq yet so I'm kind of guessing) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193461/c-sharp-linq-null-check

Comment: @rogerdeuce the referenced question is absolutely irrelevant in the context of Web APIs and Azure Mobile Services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` would mean there **is** a record for `id = 8`, but its value is `NULL'. But in your case you **do not have** a record. Which is different.

What you observe is what you **should** observe if you **do not have a record**.

And this is a standard for REST based HTTP services. If record is not there, you get an `HTTP 404` from the service.

Azure mobile services is nothing more than a combination of Web API and a wrapping (plumbing) code for your application. And every Web API call to a non-existent record would result into an HTTP 404 error.

And as already said in the comments, you should wrap your code around `try - catch` blocks and inspect the exception.

In .NET 4.5/4.6 there is new [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) type along with HttpResponseMessage and HttpRequestMessatge. The former has [EnsureSuccessStatusCode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode(v=vs.118).aspx) method. Which, if called will trigger exception.

In the older versions of the Framework there [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient_methods(v=vs.100).aspx) class, which would throw an exception if the HTTP status code is not 200.

So, again, at the end - you observe absolutely normal behavoir. Just have to read a little more about [HTTP REST](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) services, [HTTP VERBS](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) and [HTTP Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Then also understand how the particular framework you use (.NET) handles the HTTP Status Codes.

Comment: Thanks, I wrapped it in this block:  bool isUserInAzureDB = false;
                    try
                    {
                        await _AzureMobileService.GetCustomer(microsoftUserId);
                        isUserInAzureDB = true;
                    }
                    catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException zumoEx)
                    {
                        isUserInAzureDB = false;
                    }